# fread function reads only about 700kb

Tags: c, fread

I am trying to open and read 4 MB bin file, 
but I couldn't use `fread` to read more than ~700 KB.
Actually I want to open and read genesis ROM file
which is binary format that reading should be from beginning to the last byte.
When trying to read over that amount, error occurs at run time, program stops and closes.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    FILE* fp;
    int buffer[4000000];
    fp=fopen ("file.bin","rb");
    fread (buffer,sizeof(int),4000000,fp);
}
```

What is the wrong with my code?

Comment: You do know that the average stack size if somewhere between 1 and 4 megabytes? You have a stack of almost 16 megabytes. I'm surprised your program even loads.

Comment: i'm totally new in C programming , if its possible to show me how to done the mission please..

Comment: Then here's a couple of other helpful hints (unrelated to your problem here, but still good): In C never have an empty argument list when declaring a function. That means the function takes an unspecified number of unspecified arguments. And when used for `main` it's actually not valid as per the specification. If you want a function without argument used `void`, as in `int main(void) ...`. You also declare `main` to return an `int` (which is correct), but you don't actually return anything. You either need to call `exit` or `return` a value (zero means no error).

Comment: Also, you say that the files you want to read are 4 MB? Remember that an `int` is 4 bytes, so you only need a little bit over one million of them for 4MB. There may also be problems with [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), so you should probably have an array of little over 4 million _bytes_, something like `uint8_t buffer[4 * 1024 * 1024];`

Comment: @SaeedBasrah I would suggest that the negative vote you're complaining about in the answer Alex gave is due to lack of research. Which research have you done prior to asking this question? Did you read the [`fread` manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fread.html)? Having done so, don't you think the return value of `fread` is rather important? Why doesn't your code use it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "*In C never have an empty argument list when declaring a function. That means the function takes an unspecified number of unspecified arguments.*" That is only true for *function prototypes*. The C standard uses `int main()` several times in examples. Furthermore, the C standard explicitly defines what happens when you omit `return` or `exit` from `main`, but not other functions. Would you like to discuss this further in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28878/room-for-modifiable-lvalue-and-joachim-pileborg)?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour "the C standard explicitly defines ..." -- C99 and later.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes, and I don't know of many people who would think it's constructive to define C by the C89 standard. Do you?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I admit defeat about needing to use `return` from `main. And while the standard may use `int main()` in examples, at least the C99 standard says `main` shall be defined either with `void` as argument or with the `argc`/`argv` pair.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg C99 says "It shall be defined with a return type of int and with **no
parameters**: *{examples here}* or equivalent...". Section 6.7.6.3p14 says "An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty 
list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the 
function has **no parameters**." I'm done with this argument.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Maybe I'm reading 5.1.2.2.1p1 of TC3 wrong then? And in TC3 there is no section 6.7.6.3.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [Here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is a link to the C99 standard draft. Go to 5.1.2.2.1p1, read it from the very start, noting that it mentions "no parameters", gives examples and then says "or equivalent". At 6.7.6.3p14 you'll find "An empty
list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
function has no parameters", which states that `int main() { ... }` declares a function that has no parameters.

Comment: "I don't know of many people who would think it's constructive to define C by the C89 standard." -- That sounds like a strawman. Since some people are using compilers that still don't adhere to C99, and gcc still defaults to C89, and because there are some people who became familiar with the C89 standard but still haven't caught up to the changes, it can be useful to make these things clear and explicit. All I did was add the qualifier; I wasn't expecting anyone to take offense at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better choice is load file my blocks.

Also in order not to run out the stack, you should use dynamically allocated buffer, as `heap` is bigger than `stack`.

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_file(FILE* file, unsigned char* buffer);

int main ()
{
     FILE* fp;
     unsigned char* buffer = NULL;
     int bytes_read = 0;
     fp=fopen ("file.bin","rb");
     bytes_read = read_file(fp, buffer);
     return 0;
}

int read_file(FILE* file, unsigned char* buffer)
{
    int bytes_read = 0;
    int block_bytes_read = 0;
    unsigned char block[BLOCK_SIZE];

    do
    {
         block_bytes_read = fread (block,sizeof(char),BLOCK,file);
         buffer = realloc(buffer, block_bytes_read*sizeof(char));
         memcpy((buffer + bytes_read), block, block_bytes_read*sizeof(char));
         bytes_read += block_bytes_read;
    } while (block_bytes_read != 0);

   return bytes_read;

}
```

Comment: little example may solve the problem ,, how to make dynamically allocated buffer

Comment: thank you Alex  ,i will give it a try then back may be at two or three days to be honest , allso thank for all other mambers answered and gives advices  , and i beleave all answers are nice  ,,,, some one gave my Question -1 ????!!! i didnt say that i'm proffisional i admit that I totally new with C ,, and thats the correct place to ask !! or i'm wrong ?!

Comment: your sign is back Alex ;) in fact babalu deserve a sign also but there just one can be given .

Comment: @SaeedBasrah Please don't whine about downvoted questions. There's a reason that SO imposes no penalty on users to downvote questions.

Comment: Joachim PeilBorg & jim-Balter thats comfortable explanation ,,, thank you ,, and even now the downvotes becames -2 thats not matter ;) .

Answer (score 3):

Please do the read operation in a loop for a particular chunk size.

Answer (score 1):

[1] missing return (return negative to indicate error occurred)

[2] use malloc (dynamically allocate off heap) instead of stack

[3] check pointer values for file read, memory allocation & number of bytes read

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    char * buffer;
    size_t size = 4194304;
    size_t result;

    pFile = fopen ( "file.bin" , "rb" );
    if (pFile==NULL) {
       fputs ("Unable to open file",stderr); 
       return (-1);
    }

    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fputs ("Unable to allocate memory",stderr); 
        return (-2);
    }

    result = fread (buffer,1,size,pFile);
    if (result != size) {
       fputs ("Unable to read 4 MB",stderr); 
       return (-3);
    }

    fclose (pFile);
    free (buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the parenthesis in the `return` statements. `sizeof(char)` is also unnecessary, as it is always 1, though arguably helps readability.
+1, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make `buffer` a static variable, so it will not reside on the stack.

In addition, use `fread` inside a loop, since it is not guaraneed to read all the file at once.

Comment: Make buffer a static variable, so it will not reside on the stack?? thats will be great but really i'm new in C .

Comment: Just put the keyword `static` before `int buffer[4000000];`.
That's not the best solutions - other have given you better ones. that's just the quickest.

Comment: Is there any proof to suggest that an object declared with `static` storage duration can't lie on a stack?

Comment: it can't lie on the stack because it's address must be absolute. technically I think it can be put in the bottom of the stack just like any global variable, but no sane compiler will do it.

Comment: There are no global variables in C. You appear to be [misusing statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misuse_of_statistics).

Comment: If the problem is that there is no such assertion in the ANSI standard, it is not relevant for this case: on any system Saeed will try this, it will not reside on the stack.

In case I am wrong, please give me counter example.

Answer (score 0):

My biggest problem with this code is in this line:

```
fread (buffer,sizeof(int),4000000,fp);
```

This line introduces a significant list of problems, actually. Firstly, there is no guarantee that the file you're reading from was successfully opened. You need to compare `fp` to `NULL` to make that guarantee, as others have indicated. Secondly, and it seems I'm stressing this way too often: *You really should be checking the return value*. This goes for *all standard C functions*, not just *fopen* and *fread*.

The return value of *fread* tells you how many items *were actually read*. Suppose you're requesting four million `int`s, and the file only contains two. The return value will tell you that only two `int`s were read.

---

Now, onto the big stuff! Let us first consider that `sizeof(int)` differs on different implementations. Your system might read four bytes, while another might read two and another yet might read eight. This is just a basic, yet fundamental way in which *integer representation* might differ.

Let us consider a more subtle, yet equally devastating way *integer representation* might differ: Suppose your `int`s are four bytes, with the left-most bit being the least significant bit. Another machine might use the left-most bit as the *least* significant bit. Likewise, consider *endianness*, which is the order of bytes.

Suppose your `int`s are thirty-two bits, and they represent values between `-(1 << 31)` and `(1 << 31)`, which implies that there are no padding bits. Another system might use thirty-two bit integers that have sixteen bits of padding, which means it might only represent values between `-(1 << 16)` and `(1 << 16)`. Suppose those padding bits are parity bits, to ensure that RAM is functioning correctly (eg. Intel Xeon servers). Now you have a situation where your server is telling you your RAM is faulty, when it isn't.

Your code should explicitly translate from the integer representation your files use to store integers, to whichever representation your computer uses natively. When writing your integers to the file, you need to ensure that you explicitly translate your implementations representation into *that* representation. Likewise, when reading your integers back from the file, your code should explicitly translate that representation into your implementations representation.

For example, let us assume that your `int` values won't lie beyond `-32767` or `32767` (16 bit signed integer, ones' complement). It would be portable to represent this using two bytes, *but you need to define the sign and representation of that integer explicitly*. When writing, you could extract the sign and the absolute value, then write `sign * 128 + absolute_value / 256` and `absolute_value % 256` to your file. When reading, you'd then extract the sign bit, multiply and add to reconstruct your value.

---

Let us consider that your file is supposedly 4MB, yet you are reading `sizeof (int) * 4000000` values. 4MB is `0x400000`, not `sizeof (int) * 4000000`. I suppose what you really want would be something along the lines of:

```
unsigned char *foo = malloc(0x400000); /* 4MB */

/* XXX: Handle malloc errors here */
assert(foo != NULL);

FILE *fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");

/* XXX: Handle fopen errors here */
assert(fp != NULL);

size_t num_bytes_read = fread(foo, 1, 0x400000, fp);

/* XXX: Transform the bytes into integers */

free(foo);
```

---

My problem with this is that it relies upon a 4MB buffer just to read and transform bytes into integers. This task doesn't need a buffer at all!

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");

/* XXX: Handle fopen errors here */
assert(fp != NULL);

for (;;) {
    int x = fgetc(fp);

    /* XXX: Handle fgetc errors here */
    assert(x >= 0);

    int y = fgetc(fp);

    /* XXX: Handle fgetc errors here */
    assert(y >= 0);

    /* XXX: Transform the characters in x and y into the int values */
};

free(foo);
```

---

Whether or not you need to store those transformed values somewhere isn't specified in the question. If you don't need to, then my next problem is the use of an array, when you could just be reading a single item, processing it and then moving onto the next.

Comment: thats also nice explanation and helpful thanx ,,, the problem is that i am just really beginner in C programming .